# ggplot heatmap legend doesn't represent negative numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, heatmap

I'm trying to make a heat map for a data set that includes negative numbers:

```
Ne      BR         Error  
10000   0.00001    1.62  
10000   0.000001  -1.03  
10000   0.0000001 -0.124  
100000  0.00001   36.73  
100000  0.000001   5.86  
100000  0.0000001 -0.79  
1000000 0.00001   -8.335  
1000000 0.000001  39.465  
1000000 0.0000001  2.59
```

I've used this code:

```
library(ggplot2)  
data = read.csv('full_path')  
(p <- ggplot(data[1:9,], aes(Ne, BR)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Error), colour="white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="black") + scale_x_log('Ne') +    
  scale_y_log('Birth Rate') + opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank()))
```

This produces a fine heatmap, but the legend doesn't account for the negative numbers.  The colors appear to correctly reflect the negative values, but the legend stops at zero, which is light grey.  How can I get a legend out of this that covers the full range of the data in the 'Error' column of my dataframe?

Comment: You'll need to provide a reproducible example that demonstrates the behavior you describe, I think.

Comment: How is this not reproducible?  If I can figure out how, I'll upload the resulting figure.

Comment: Well, you edited the question. It originally had ggplot code that referred to variables not in the data you supplied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Ne, BR)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Error), colour="white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="black",breaks = seq(min(dat$Error),max(dat$Error),length.out = 5)) + scale_x_log('Ne') +    
  scale_y_log('Birth Rate') + opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank())
```

`ggplot` is just trying to pick 'nice' breaks in the scale for you, similarly to how axis tick marks are chosen. (I changed your data frame name to `dat`, as `data` is a commonly used function in R. It's not a huge deal, but it avoids confusion.)

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works nicely.  Thank you!  Very strange though that a 'nice' break would mean ignoring some of the data.

Comment: @Jake Well, it's not really 'ignoring' the data. Consider the axis tick mark analogy. One would expect there to be data points beyond the first and last tick marks on the x axis in a scatterplot. It's just using the same strategy, which admittedly causes a fair degree of confusion. Just remember that changing `breaks` _does not alter how the data are binned_, it only changed what's displayed in the legend.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the explanations.  And the solution of course.